# Howto bootstrap Backbone app with yeoman having require.js enabled

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, amd, yeoman

I'm playing with yeoman for a time now. I wonder how I accomplish bootstrapping a Backbone application and having require.js enabled at the same time.

```
yeoman init
```

provides me with a setup where I can work with modules in AMD style.

```
yeoman init backbone:all
```

provides me with a Backbone scaffold but I had to "include" all my models, collection etc. manually in index.html.

Is there a way to have both?

Regards Felix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already an open [issue](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/76) for this. Add your thoughts there :)

Answer (score 5):

We have updated the Yeoman [backbone generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone) to support [RequireJS](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/pull/22). But it not officially added to npm. But you can try it using

```
npm install git://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone.git
```

Discussion : [Not found in npm install](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/issues/9)

The backbone generator supports yeoman 1.0beta. Try

```
yo backbone
```

You will receive a conditional prompt for RequireJS.

**UPDATE 1**

[Backbone generartor](https://npmjs.org/package/generator-backbone) is available on npm.
Try `npm install generator-backbone`

**UPDATE 2**
RequireJS with `--coffee` option is now supported in [backbone generator v0.2.2](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/releases)

Comment: I don't get a prompt for require.js. Is this still valid?

Comment: Ah. `RequireJS is not supported with --coffee option for now.`

Comment: @JordanFeldstein We already received a [pull request](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/pull/171) for RequireJS + CS. we are testing it. expect it the very next release.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I developed a generator for that, take a look at https://github.com/abiee/generator-backbone-amd

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same today. What I did ultimately was to perform yeoman init first. Then again yeoman install backbone. Console will ask if you want to override files. Do not override main.js & index.html. Rest you may.

This won't give you perfect start. But, most of the things will be in place.

Comment: Thats the way I did it then.