# Yeoman use Backbone/Ember with requireJs

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, yeoman

I would like to use Yeoman to start a project with a framework and requireJs enabled.

If I init a project with Amd and install backbone after, the models/controllers/routes... aren't generated with requireJs.

I have find this topic :
[Howto bootstrap Backbone app with yeoman having require.js enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153359/howto-bootstrap-backbone-app-with-yeoman-having-require-js-enabled)

But the link of the response is dead... :(

Answer (score 1):

If it helps in any way, I ported over the Peepcode Backbone project to a RequireJS and Yeoman-enabled one here: https://github.com/vishvish/backbone-peepcode-reboot

Yeoman has just changed its MO, and I don't know if that will work with it, but the models, routes, etc, are all there in RequireJS format, hopefully that will help you be on your way.

Answer (score 0):

We have updated the Yeoman [backbone generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone) to support both [twitter bootstrap](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/pull/17) and [RequireJS](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/pull/22). But it not officially added to npm. But you can try it using

```
npm install git://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone.git
```

Discussion : [Not found in npm install](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/issues/9)